# Is there anything that I can do while waiting for the decision on scholarship

Tags: phd, application, funding

I applied for a PhD degree and has received an offer for it! However, I have to wait until next two months to know whether they give me a scholarship as well. I'm very nervous as the number of scholarships is limited and it's highly unlikely that I can join the programme without it. I am also applying for other universities as well but none of them offer scholarship covering everything for international student like the one I'm waiting for.

Is there anything that I can do while waiting in order to strengthen my application?

Comment: In two months there is very little you can do. Fishing might teach you patience. Or perhaps, write a paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The period between admissions and scholarship decisions is not really any different from the period between submission and acceptance notification.

If you have any *major* changes in your status—if you receive a significant award ("Best paper," teaching award, or similar), or if you have made a notable research contribution (*published* a paper, or at least submitted one), then that would be relevant information for the department. Otherwise, you'll just have to bide your time.